# Mongo pipeline stage giving unexpected value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, pipeline

**percentCompletion** is coming out as null in some cases(where fields inside $add are null) despite trying to mitigate the null value

```
{
  "percentCompletion": {
    $multiply: [
      {
        $divide: [
          {
            $add: ["$PROCUREMENT", "$SERVICEORDER", "$MATERIALTRANSFER", 0]
          },
          {
            $cond: {
              if: { $or: [{ $eq: ["$MATERIAL", null] }, { $eq: ["$MATERIAL", 0] }] },
              then: 1,
              else: "$MATERIAL"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      100
    ]
  }
}
```

1. `$add: ["$PROCUREMENT", "$SERVICEORDER", "$MATERIALTRANSFER", 0]`

taking output 0 here even if all first three fields are 0.

2.

```
$cond: {
          if: { $or: [{ $eq: ["$MATERIAL", null] }, { $eq: ["$MATERIAL", 0] }] },
          then: 1,
          else: "$MATERIAL"
        }
```

divider is 1 in case the value of `MATERIAL` is either null or 0, else it's own value

EDIT - yes `$PROCUREMENT`, `$SERVICEORDER`, `$MATERIALTRANSFER` can all be null in some cases.

sample output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6154501b13b518292f34a969"),
    "clientName" : "Mahadev",
    "projectNumber" : "1345",
    "MATERIAL" : 4500.0,
    "PROCUREMENT" : NumberInt(0),
    "SERVICEORDER" : null,
    "MATERIALTRANSFER" : null,
    "percentCompletion" : null,
    "dateDifferenceInDays" : null
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data and expected result? Thanks.

Comment: Can any of PROCUREMENT, SERVICEORDER or MATERIALTRANSFER be null?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes they can all be null in some cases, but since ive added 4th element 0 in $add, i expect the numerator to be 0 in that particular case, as for denominator i've added conditions aswell

Comment: @YongShun Hey, I've added a sample unexpected output("percentCompletion" : null), expected should be "percentCompletion" : 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `$ifNull`:

```
     percentCompletion: {
        $multiply: [
          {$divide: [      
              {$add: [
                  {$ifNull: ["$PROCUREMENT", 0]},
                  {$ifNull: ["$SERVICEORDER", 0]},
                  {$ifNull: ["$MATERIALTRANSFER", 0]}
              ]},
              {$cond: [{$eq: [{$ifNull: ["$MATERIAL", 0]}, 0]}, 1, "$MATERIAL"]}
          ]},
          100
        ]
      }
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rQA_sGdJ1B1)